# Python Pandas equivalent for SQL case statement using lead and lag window function

Tags: python, sql, pandas, window-functions, case-statement

New to Python here and trying to see if there is a more elegant solution.

I have a time series data of telematics devices that has motion indicator. I need to expand the motion indicator to +/- 1 row of the actual motion start and stop (denoted by motion2 column below). I was doing it in SQL using case statements and lead and lag window functions. Trying to convert my codes to python...

Here is the data.
    import pandas as pd

```
data = {'device':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 
    'time':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
    'motion':[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df = df[['device','time','motion']]

##sort data chronologically for each device
df.sort_values(['device','time'], ascending = True, inplace = True)
```

This is how df looks like

```
device, time, motion
1,1,0
1,2,0
1,3,1
1,4,1
1,5,1
1,6,0
1,7,0
1,8,0
1,9,1
1,10,1
1,11,0
1,12,0
2,5,0
2,6,0
2,7,0
2,8,1
2,9,1
2,10,1
2,11,0
2,12,1
2,13,0
2,14,0
```

What I need is the motion2 column below added to the data frame.

```
device, time, motion, motion2
1,1,0,0
1,2,0,1
1,3,1,1
1,4,1,1
1,5,1,1
1,6,0,1
1,7,0,0
1,8,0,1
1,9,1,1
1,10,1,1
1,11,0,1
1,12,0,0
2,5,0,0
2,6,0,0
2,7,0,1
2,8,1,1
2,9,1,1
2,10,1,1
2,11,0,1
2,12,1,1
2,13,0,1
2,14,0,0
```

Below is the python code that does works. However, wondering if there is a more elegant way.

```
##create new columns for prior and next motion indicator
df['prev_motion'] = df.groupby(['device'])['motion'].shift(1)
df['next_motion'] = df.groupby(['device'])['motion'].shift(-1)

##create the desired motion2 indicator to expand +/- 1 record of the motion 
start and stop

df['motion2'] = df[['prev_motion', 'motion', 'next_motion']].apply(lambda 
row: 1 if row['motion']==1 else (1 if row['prev_motion']==1 or 
row['next_motion']==1 else 0), axis=1)

##drop unwanted columns        
df.drop(columns=['prev_motion', 'next_motion'], inplace = True)
```

This was much easier in SQL using case statement and windows functions (lead and lag).

```
case 
when motion = 1 then 1
when motion = 0 and (lead(motion) over (partition by device order by time) = 1) then 1
when motion = 0 and (lag(motion) over (partition by device order by time) = 1) then 1
else 0
end as motion2
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't necessarily the most elegant, but it works: find any point where `motion` is `1`, or where `motion` shifted by 1 in either direction is `1`. Here are 2 ways to do that with `numpy` functions (note that `numpy` functions don't require explicitely importing `numpy`, as they are also built into `pandas` and can be accessed via `pd.np`, but see @Abhi's comment for a pure `pandas` equivalent):

```
df['motion2'] = pd.np.where(df.motion.values|pd.np.roll(df.motion.values,1)|pd.np.roll(df.motion.values,-1),1,0)

# The following is Essentially the equivalent, but maybe a bit clearer / more efficient
df['motion2'] = pd.np.stack((df.motion.values,pd.np.roll(df.motion.values,1),pd.np.roll(df.motion.values,-1))).any(0).astype(int)

>>> df
    device  time  motion  motion2
0        1     1       0        0
1        1     2       0        1
2        1     3       1        1
3        1     4       1        1
4        1     5       1        1
5        1     6       0        1
6        1     7       0        0
7        1     8       0        1
8        1     9       1        1
9        1    10       1        1
10       1    11       0        1
11       1    12       0        0
12       2     5       0        0
13       2     6       0        0
14       2     7       0        1
15       2     8       1        1
16       2     9       1        1
17       2    10       1        1
18       2    11       0        1
19       2    12       1        1
20       2    13       0        1
21       2    14       0        0
```

Comment: `pd.concat([df.motion.shift(-1),df.motion.shift(1),df.motion],axis=1).max(axis=1)`

Comment: @Abhi, that would work, it's essentially the same underlying mechanism as what I proposed, just using `pandas` functions rather than `numpy`. As using `numpy` functions doesn't require explicitly importing it as a separate package (they can be accessed with `pd.np.whatever_function()...`), I prefer those, but it's personal preference :)

Comment: It's good. I haven't played around with numpy a lot so I usually use pandas most of the times. :) +1

Comment: Yeah, it's nice you pointed it out, I referenced your comment in an edit, in case someone is strongly opposed to the `numpy` methods. Thanks!

Comment: I realized this wasn't perfectly accurate solution. I also need to partition the window by device. Looks like if the last motion row for device 1 = 1 and the first row for device 2 =0, the device 2 first row still gets motion2=1 even when device 2 second row =0. How would you partition by device and still perform same operations? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I hadn't seen that requirement in your original question, sorry! You could do: `df['motion2'] = df.groupby('device')['motion'].transform(lambda x: pd.np.stack((x.values, pd.np.roll(x.values,1), pd.np.roll(x.values,-1))).any(0).astype(int))`

Answer (score 0):

One option to replicate SQL's `case_when` is [case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.case_when.case_when) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd

In [5]: df.case_when(
   ...:     df.motion.eq(1), 1,
   ...:     df.motion.eq(0) & df.groupby('device').motion.shift(-1), 1,
   ...:     df.motion.eq(0) & df.groupby('device').motion.shift(), 1,
   ...:     0,
   ...:     column_name = 'motion2')
Out[5]:
    device  time  motion  motion2
0        1     1       0        0
1        1     2       0        1
2        1     3       1        1
3        1     4       1        1
4        1     5       1        1
5        1     6       0        1
6        1     7       0        0
7        1     8       0        1
8        1     9       1        1
9        1    10       1        1
10       1    11       0        1
11       1    12       0        0
12       2     5       0        0
13       2     6       0        0
14       2     7       0        1
15       2     8       1        1
16       2     9       1        1
17       2    10       1        1
18       2    11       0        1
19       2    12       1        1
20       2    13       0        1
21       2    14       0        0
```